# How to add to std::map an object with constant field?

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

Suppose I have the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

struct A {
    const int value;
    A(int value) : value{value} {}
};

int main() {
    A a{3};
    std::map<std::string, A> myMap;
    myMap["Hello"] = a; // Error: Copy assignment operator of 'A' is implicitly deleted because 
                        //        field 'value' is of const-qualified type 'const int'.
    return 0;
}
```

Well I understand the error. But I can't override `operator=` for this type of structure, because it has `const int value` field. So what should I do?

Commenters here suggest different solutions with their own pros and cons. Let me clear up the behaviour I need.

1. `const int value` is constant forever. No tricks or hacks to modify it.
2. If the key doesn't exist in a `map`, then assignment means "add pair [key, value] to the map". But if the key exists, then replace the value.
3. No default creation of `A` objects. Accessing to `map` using a key that doesn't exist in a map should throw an error or abort or something. But creating default 'A' objects for an unexisting key **is not allowed**.

If I understand all the presented solutions, the best thing I can do is to create some wrapper around `std::map`. How do you think?

Comment: Don't you also need a zero argument constructor to be able to use `operator[](Key)` on a map?

Comment: @BillLynch You mean, if there is no such key, std::map constructs `A{0}' and creates a key that points to 'A{0}`? If so, then no, I don't need such functionality. I need my map to be consistent, i.e. it should contain only key-value pairs that have been explicitly added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`map::emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) to construct `A` in-place:

```
myMap.emplace("Hello", 3);
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/zeYdjrz7z)

> If the key doesn't exist in a map, then assignment means "add pair
> [key, value] to the map". But if the key exists, then replace the
> value.

As @Serge Ballesta commented, when the key already exists, you need to erase the node from the map and emplace a new node:

```
const char* key = "Hello";
const int value = 3;
const auto it = myMap.find(key);
if (it != myMap.end())
  myMap.erase(it);
myMap.emplace(key, value);
```

Comment: It is indeed the way to go, but there is a strong difference between `operator =` and `emplace`. If the key already exists, `operator =` will change the existing value, while emplace will not. You must erase the previous value (if it exists) to keep `operator =` behaviour

Comment: @SergeBallesta If the key already exists, neither can change the value because it has a `const` data member

Comment: @Caleth: this is the reason why I say that the previous key-value pair should be erased first, to be able to emplace the new value with a non-existant key.

Comment: @康桓瑋 You can remove `else` branch, and place `myMap.emplace(key, value);` out of `if` branch.

Answer (score -1):

struct A as the value of map, need a constructer and a operator=():

```cpp
struct A {
  const int32_t value;
  A(): value(0) {}
  A(int32_t value) : value(value) {}

  A& operator=(const A& other) {
    // this change the value, if don't want change it, ignore this.
    // this is an undefined behavior. ignore this.
    // const_cast<int32_t&>(value) = other.value;
    return *this;
  }
};
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `A(): value(0) {}` constructor?

Comment: _Modifying a const object through a non-const access path  results in **undefined behavior**._ See, e.g., https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast or http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.cv#4.sentence-1.

Comment: @ЕвгенийПавлов if key not exist, map need a purpose constructor to create a object  of A.

Comment: @dyungwang Sorry that I edited my question too late, but I don't need `A` objects to be created default.

Comment: @ЕвгенийПавлов: `map::operator[]` requires default constructor though. (In addition to your `const` isuue for assignment).

Comment: @ЕвгенийПавлов shared_ptr or unique_ptr may help, something like std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<A>>, :)